# File permission in htdocs

Tags: xampp

How can I grant permission to these files:

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 yaska yaska    4096 Jun  8 12:41 database
-rwxr-xr-x  1 yaska yaska 1015333 Jun  8 12:41 driving_school.sql
-rwxr-xr-x  1 yaska yaska   12292 Jun  8 12:41 .DS_Store 
drwxr-xr-x  8 yaska yaska    4096 Jun  8 12:41 .git
-rwxr-xr-x  1 yaska yaska     167 Jun  8 12:41 .htaccess
-rwxrwxrwx  1 yaska yaska    9838 Jun  8 12:41 index.php
```

I have tried chmod 755 and 777, but cannot access the files 
because am getting

```
This page isn’t working localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500
```

Comment: I think giving the execute permission to normal files is wrong here!

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish? "How can I grant permission to these files:"  you already have. At least IF yasha is your webservers USER. "I have tried chmod 755 and 777,"  that's never the correct answer. And 750 is the most you need. What you need to do is fix your webserver configuration. And no as you do not show us ... we can't answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting an HTTP error, you are connecting via HTTP, perhaps using a browser to access the files.

Solution: Don't use a browser, use a terminal instead.